# Upgrading an Ubuntu localrepo from trusty to xenial

Tags: apt, repository, apt-mirror, source-packages

Please forgive my ignorance as I am new to Ubuntu.
I have created a local repository of Trusty using apt-mirror.
My question is how to upgrade this repo to Xenial?
Also in the mirror.list file how to limit the download of deb-src files to amd64 only.
Thanks in advance for your bearing with me :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ubuntu. Please do not be sorry for being "new" to Ubuntu. Everyone has been at some point for it has not existed since the dawn of ages.

Here is my configuration for xenial to come : the file is /etc/apt/mirror.list

```
############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /home/your/path/apt/ubuntu/
#
set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
set skel_path    $base_path/skel
set var_path     $base_path/var
set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     1
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Note : I set set nthreads 1 because my internet connection is allergic to aggressive downloading and when apt-mirror is doing its "thing" the whole rest of the house looses service. You could set at anywhere between 5 to 20 and it could do it for you.

And in /etc/cron.d/apt-mirror , I have

```
0 4    * * *   apt-mirror      /usr/bin/apt-mirror > /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/cron.log
```

Remember the official repo is not out yet. This will be working when the time comes.

Here is an example of the command line output when I call apt-mirror (for trusty as of now) from the command line :

```
pi@bananapi:~$ apt-mirror
Downloading 152 index files using 1 threads...
Begin time: Mon Mar 28 23:34:49 2016
[1]... [0]... 
End time: Mon Mar 28 23:39:01 2016

Processing tranlation indexes: [TTTT]

Downloading 213 translation files using 1 threads...
Begin time: Mon Mar 28 23:39:01 2016
[1]... [0]... 
End time: Mon Mar 28 23:40:09 2016

Processing indexes: [PPPP]

68.5 GiB will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 26918 archive files using 1 threads...
Begin time: Mon Mar 28 23:42:24 2016
[1]...
```

Hope it helps you.

Regards.

Marc